# how to install openJDK-7-jdk on Ubuntu for non-privilige user?

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I have no root access to java JDK 7 so I install java JDK to a folder and extract it

```
http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u21-b11/jdk-7u21-linux-i586.tar.gz
```

Then if I call it:

```
./bin/java -version
```

it works and shows the version. but now I want to configure Eclipse to use that new version but it requires to link it to OpenJDK which I dont know how to install it to my desired folder as I did for the step above. 
so briefly, how can I install openJDK inside my folder and make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

edit your eclipse.ini file and add a "-vm" with the full path to the java command to use

Comment: when I dont have privilege means I cant edit that file.

Comment: Do not install Eclipse from the repositories. That is outdated in almost all distributions. Just unzip a download from the Eclipse website to any directory you like. There you can also edit the eclipse.ini.

Answer (score 0):

Don't `sudo apt-get install sun-java7-jdk` work as a unprivileged user? (i couldn't comment sorry).

You could check out http://168.site90.net/doku.php?id=ubuntu-download-and-install-jdk-bin

That may help you.

Comment: "sudo (pron.: /ˈsuːduː/[2] or /ˈsuːdoʊ/) is a program for Unix-like computer operating systems that allows users to run programs with the security privileges of another user (normally the superuser, or root)." - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo

Comment: @Tyler no it doesnt work for unprivileged user.

Comment: Oh okay my bad, never tried anything as a unprivileged user. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to just download the ubuntu deb packages and extract them to a local folder. Execute `apt-get -y --print-uris install openjdk-7-jdk` to show you what packages you need, then download and extract them.

script to do everything:

```
apt-get -y --print-uris install openjdk-7-jdk | grep "http.*deb" -o | xargs wget
for d in *.deb; do dpkg -x "$d" openjdk; done
rm *.deb
```

Now you should have everything extracted to a folder `openjdk`.

From what I've tried the java installed like this seems to work fine, you just neet to point eclipse to the new vm.